# fair and double head coin

Tags: probability

**Question :** I have a fair coin and a two-headed coin. I choose one of the two coins randomly with equal probability and flip it. Given that the flip was heads, what is the probability that I flipped the two-headed coin

Probability of picking a coin is 1/2.  probability of head in two headed coin is 1. 
[image]

Is this answer correct?

Comment: hint...you are looking for a conditional probability

Comment: Not quite right yet. Finish the tree showing all four leaves with probability $1/4$ for each. How many heads? Of those, how many with the unfair coin?

Comment: @Ethan Bolker There will be three because one coin is double head

Answer (score 2):

If $DH$ stands for double-headed coin, and $H$ for Heads, you need $$p(DH|H)=\frac{p(DH\cap H)}{p(H)}$$
$$=\frac{\frac 12\times 1}{\frac 12\times 1+\frac 12\times\frac 12}$$
$$=\frac 23$$

Answer (score 0):

Define the following events:

- $E = \{\text{flip head}\}$
- $E_1 = \{\text{pick the two headed coin}\}$
- $E_2 = \{\text{pick the fair coin}\}$

We want to compute the probability of $E_1$, given $E$.

Note that $E_1$ and $E_2$ is a partition of the sample space. By the Baye's rule
$$
\mathbb{P}(E_1 | E) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(E | E_1) \mathbb{P}(E_1)}{\mathbb{P}(E | E_1) \mathbb{P}(E_1) + \mathbb{P}(E | E_2) \mathbb{P}(E_2)}
$$

It is easy to see that

- $\mathbb{P}(E | E_1) \mathbb{P}(E_1) = \frac{1}{2}$
- $\mathbb{P}(E | E_2) \mathbb{P}(E_2) = \frac{1}{4}$

Therefore,
$$
\mathbb{P}(E_1 | E) = \frac{2}{3}
$$